# Why is it important to have stable activations in the forward pass?

Tags: deep-learning

In many sources on the literature on weight initialization, I find the idea that it's a good idea to keep the activations stable through the layers, that is making sure they stay about the same size/order of magnitude as you go through the layers. Sometimes it's implied that this has something to do with avoiding exploding or vanishing gradients.

For example in [this blog article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-initialize-a-neural-network-27564cfb5ffc):

> During the forward step, the activations (**and then the gradients**) can quickly get really big or really small — this is due to the fact that we repeat a lot of matrix multiplications. Either of these effects is fatal for training.

But why? To me this seems like an non sequitur, I don't see why unstable activations would imply unstable gradients. The only thing I can think of is that if we have an edge with weight $w$ connecting a node with activation $f(x)$ into a node with pre-activation $y$, we have the following formula:

$$
\frac{\partial C}{\partial w} =
f(x)\frac{\partial C}{\partial y}
$$

Is it just because the activation $f(x)$ appears in that formula? I'm not sure because no source that I've found explicitly says this. But what if the differential $\frac{\partial C}{\partial y}$ cancels out the effect of $f(x)$, for instance if the activations get really big as we go through the layers, but the differentials get really small, and it cancels out?